# ch340g usb to ttl error: ch341-uart ttyUSB0: failed to read modem status: -110

Tags: drivers, usb

im using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

when i try to upload from arduino i get

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Input/output error
```

when i try to open serial monitor

```
Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyUSB0'. (Port not found)
```

if i use another type of usb to serial (pl2303) serial monitor is working fine
the hardware is working fine i tested on a windows machine and no problem.

```
$ lsmod | grep usbserial
usbserial              53248  2 pl2303,ch341
```

dmesg gives:

```
[  451.329190] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  451.505205] usb 10-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.54
[  451.505219] usb 10-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  451.505223] usb 10-2: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[  451.556668] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  451.556686] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  451.558302] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
[  451.559378] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[  451.559976] ch341 10-2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[  451.573480] usb 10-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  463.937493] usb 10-2: failed to receive control message: -110
[  463.937504] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: failed to read modem status: -110
[  482.625628] usb 10-2: failed to receive control message: -110
[  482.625701] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: failed to read modem status: -110
[  501.281699] usb 10-2: failed to receive control message: -110
[  501.281710] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: failed to read modem status: -110
```

and with pl2303:

```
[ 1751.189867] usb 10-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1751.190187] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1751.190220] ch341 10-2:1.0: device disconnected
[ 1786.822056] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1786.996937] usb 10-2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303, bcdDevice= 3.00
[ 1786.996946] usb 10-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1786.996951] usb 10-2: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[ 1786.996954] usb 10-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[ 1787.046337] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[ 1787.046367] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[ 1787.046410] pl2303 10-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 1787.076108] usb 10-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I tried a lot of things like adding user to dialout and file permissions

what can be done?

edit:

```
ls -al /dev/ | grep ttyUSB*
crw-rw----   1 ss   dialout   188,   0 dec 19 16:58 ttyUSB0
```

same for both devices

edit:

after

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout username && sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0 && sudo chown root:dialout -R /dev/

ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 dec 19 20:40 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

arduino serial monitor same error and dmesg same as above

update:

installed arduino on another machine (same laptop with windows7 different hdd) only run the add user to dialout group and is working fine uploaded a test sketch from arduino. Same version "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
The laptop is an older model only usb2.0 the pc is "newer" (5-6 years old) and using a usb3.0 port. Switch to a 2.0 port and now is better but other problem:
serial monitor is picking up random characters at random intervals:

```
MCbK19:kEPUqPJv0Zyq71dlX19QDFDFR
2K19:m4GjpRJ7cNnR9AxB
X19K19:M4yD0kmEvONihR79X19
DFUDK19:OVyzqIbEKK4VAUCcX19DF
```

?????

i can upload a sketch if i manage to send between the random chars.

Problem resolved by using a USB2.0 port.

Comment: are the device nodes present? `ls -al /dev/ | grep ttyUSB*` please.  [edit] your question for reply.

Comment: Please run `sudo usermod -a -G dialout username && sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0 && sudo chown root:dialout -R /dev/ ` and check again `ls -al /dev/tty*`

Comment: i think you need to manually reset to do the upload, cause DTR and RST held on reset mode, add 100nf capacitor to convert into low pulse. i really to recommended to buy FTDI FT232 breakout. they have the DTR pin to do automatic reset. make sure to use 115200 baudrate.

Comment: i'm not at that part yet. the converter is not working, i have a wire soldered on the converter to grab the DTR signal and is working ok on a windows machine. it should be able to do serial monitor with TX-RX connected and return the data send. i tried with Putty and get "unable to open serial port"

Comment: @sergiu sora what the board are you using?, install the driver to read the port or add udev rule manually.

Comment: @abu-ahmed al-khatiri  converter is: [link](https://icmasteronline.com/product/3-3v-5v-usb-to-ttl-converter-ch340g-uart-serial-adapter-module-stc/)

Comment: @sergiu sora seems like the usb2serial is not created udev default rule to read your tty, try to add new rule to `/etc/udev/rule.d/prolific.rules` and add lines `#udev rules for prolific usb2serial boards
ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB%n"`

Comment: there is no  prolific.rules `/etc/udev/rules.d$ ls
40-dfuse.rules       59-smfp_samsung.rules  <br/>     99-arduino-101.rules
49-stlinkv1.rules  <br/>  70-snap.picard.rules        99-jlink.rules<br/>
49-stlinkv2-1.rules  70-snap.qelectrotech.rules  avrisp.rules
49-stlinkv2.rules    70-snap.snapd.rules         z010_mchp_tools.rules
49-stlinkv3.rules    70-snap.snap-store.rules    z011_mchp_jlink.rules
51-android.rules     90-extraacl.rules           z012_mchp_efr.rules
56-hpmud.rules       98-openocd.rules`

Comment: @sergiu sora that's problem, add new file of prolific.rules and add lines above.